# VB.NET: How to reload a form when a new user logs in?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am developing an application in that user log in with his details based on his role we show different buttons and text boxes in the main form. But after logout, if login with different user names it is showing some details. This means my main form doesn't reload. Form load functions not executing. I am new to VB.NET can anyone please help me.

Comment: Code please. Otherwise no help

Comment: Sorry, we can't possibly help with code we can't see.